# How can I fix this violation of this 'react/no-unescaped-entitie' of an ESLint rule?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

This is my code:

```
const func = () => {
  return (
    <div >
       you're free
      </div>
  )}
```

Somehow ESLint flags the line "you're free" with error `error HTML entities must be escaped react/no-unescaped-entities`

However, from what I can see, JSX has escaped the apostrophes already. I can see the words `you're free` is rendered without issue. If I escape it as `&#39;`, then it will be very hard for me to search for the string (I would expect a search of `you're free` in an editor to return a hit. But obviously the editor will miss because the text is actually `you&#39;re free`)

So what is the best way to address this ESLint exception?

Comment: I prefer to be able to write you're free instead of something ridiculous like you&apos;re free. Is there any good reason why I cant just disable the react/no-unescaped-entities rule?

Comment: related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/37620#discussioncomment-2924106)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Recommended solution is to use `&apos;`, `&lsquo;` or `&rsquo;` instead of wrapping it as a variable. So like this:

```
const func = () => {
  return (
    <div >
       you&apos;re free
      </div>
  )}
```

For search-ability, it's recommended you have files for localization/internationalization and call them into your app.

Comment: This is the best and cleanest way to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @RuChernChong! :)

Comment: Another easy way is create the string as a separate variable. `const func = () => {
  const text = \`you're free\`;
  return (
    <div >
       {text}
      </div>
  )};`

then eslint shouldn't complain about curly braces

Comment: I am searching for a solution which will auto-fix these issues with the `--fix` flag. I've a lot of these warnings and I can't do a find-and-replace as there are a lot of string literals in the same files which have a `'` in them. Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think it's super clear that this is actually better... This makes it a lot harder to read your markup. IMO do {`you're free`} so you're not a human reading machine code

Comment: Hi, about the "recommended solution"  => by whom? What's the consequence of not escaping those characters? Edit: this link seems relevant: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unescaped-entities.md also show how to restrict the characters (I dislike escaping all apostrophes...)

Comment: I personally don't see a good reason to do this and will be turning this rule off.

Answer (score 102):

By the way, you can disable this kind of warnings by adding

```
"rules": { "react/no-unescaped-entities": 0 }
```

to your `.eslintrc` file.

Comment: Is there any reason I wouldn't want to do this? IE why is it a rule in the first place by default

Comment: @Andrew https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unescaped-entities.md explains why it's a rule - it's supposed to help you from making silly mistakes

Comment: I will also be disabling this rule since I've never had any issues with it.

Answer (score 29):

I had the same issue with `next.js`. I opened the `.eslintrc.json` and added the following:

```json
{
  "rules": { "react/no-unescaped-entities": 0 }
}
```

Now my `.eslintrc.json` will look as follows:

```json
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "rules": { "react/no-unescaped-entities": 0 }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

I explicitly escape the whole block of text by enclosing the line in `{" "}`:

```
const func = () => {
  return (
    <div >
       {" you're free "}
      </div>
  )}
```

Comment: Recommneded solution is to use `&apos;` instead of wrapping it as a variable.

Comment: [eslint] Curly braces are unnecessary here. (react/jsx-curly-brace-presence)

Answer (score 9):

You can do two things,

1. It can be escaped with `&apos;`

   E.g.,

   ```
       const func = () => {
         return (
           <div >
              you&apos;re free
             </div>
         )}
   ```
2. Or you need to disable some ESLint rules. For disabling the ESLint rules, first find `.eslintrc.json` in the project directory, and then paste these lines there.

   ```
   {
     "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
     "rules": {
       "react/no-unescaped-entities": "off",
       "@next/next/no-page-custom-font": "off"
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 7):

The previous solutions work only in some cases.  It wasn't working for me.  In my case, I think it's because we're also using [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) in our project.  To resolve the error, I wrapped the copy in backticks.

```
const func = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {`
        You're free.
      `}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: [eslint] Curly braces are unnecessary here. (react/jsx-curly-brace-presence)

Answer (score 7):

add this on the file that is causing the error

```
/* eslint-disable react/no-unescaped-entities */
```

also add this in the **eslintrc.json** file

```
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "rules": {
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": "off",
    "@next/next/no-page-custom-font": "off"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this extension in Visual Studio Code to fix these issues: *[html-entities](https://github.com/christopherstyles/vscode-html-entities)*

It is a good programming practice to not disable the HTML entity warning as it can help prevent some issues.

Comment: This was a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me without any ESLint errors:

```
const func = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {"you're"} free
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Curly braces are unnecessary here (.react/jsx-curly-brace-presence}

Comment: That just gives another eslint error since the braces are unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix the `react/no-unescaped-entities` error is by assigning the text with the escape character in it to a variable and then referencing the variable in the JXS.

Further reading:

- [Disallow unescaped HTML entities from appearing in markup (react/no-unescaped-entities)](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unescaped-entities.md)

```jsx
const func = () => {
  const text = `you're free`;
  return (
    <div>
      {text}
    </div>
  )}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line on top to disable the error for entire file

```
/* eslint-disable react/no-unescaped-entities */
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **backtick** is more elegant to avoid this mistake:

```
const func = () => {
  return (
    <div >
       {`you're free`}
      </div>
  )}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue in my upcoming project and successfully resolved it by encapsulating my code within backticks (``).